# GraphLoader is not working

Tags: datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am using dse-5-0-5 and graphloader to load data from GraphML. While giving command:

graphloader ./scripts/graphml2Vertex/recipeMappingGraphML.groovy -graph testGraphML -address 172.31.35.238 -load_failure_log /home/centos/DSE/dse-graph-loader-5.0.5/scripts/graphml2Vertex/loadfailure.log -dryrun true

I am getting error:
 **groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.datastax.dsegraphloader.api.GraphSource$VerticesBuilder.withVertexId() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:19)
        at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.cli.GroovyScriptExecutor.evaluate(GroovyScriptExecutor.java:106)
        at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.cli.Executable.execute(Executable.java:72)
        at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.cli.Executable.main(Executable.java:171)**

I have imported the data as graphML from orientdb (by using g.saveGraphML(filename.xml) funtion ) and now trying to include the same data in DSE graph using graphloader (import graphMl) .Can you please tell the cause of this kind of error?

-Varun

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered yesterday that the `withVertexId()` needs to be removed in order for graphloader to run the Mapping Script. I'll be changing the documentation.

Comment: Thanks . That helped. Now I am trying to view the graph in DSE Studio that I have inserted with Graphloader GraphMl. But somehow I am not able to see the graph . What could be the possible reasons. Is there any data directory for cassandra we have to give in studio distribution to help it pick up the graph ? Or am I missing some other configuration ?

Comment: Hmm, just ran a test myself. Not sure why, I'm asking the DSE Studio team about it, but the notebook doesn't get the graph. Use the 3-bar pulldown in the upper lefthand corner to "Configure this notebook" and you'll see that Default Graph is unset. Set it to the graph, and everything will work as expected. Also, in very general queries, you may need to allow scans with `schema.config().option('graph.allow_scan').set('true')`.

Comment: @user2756943, I assume you are using one of the 1.0.x versions of Studio. If so, you can test your connection in the connection details panel. Make sure your graph name is filled in there and it will validate everything - the IP, permissions, graph existence, etc. If the connection is good then you should be ready to rock!